# Multiple rest operators not allowed in parameter list?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

```
function unshift(array, ...int) {
  return [...int].concat(array);
}

function unshift(...array, ...int) {
  return [...int, ...array];
}
```

The first function is fine but not the second one, so there's no such thing as multiple rest argument in function?

Comment: And what sense would it make? Where do you expect array to finish and int to start?

Comment: To be pedantic, this is not the "rest operator". It's "rest parameter syntax" or "rest parameter notation".

Answer (score 5):

Correct.  Using the Rest operator on any parameter but the last results in a `SyntaxError`.

And it makes sense...

The Rest operator on the parameter tells the compiler to grab all remaining arguments.  If the first parameter had a rest operator, it would grab all the arguments, after which any subsequent parameters would be `undefined`.

For this reason, the Rest parameter can only be on the last parameter in the argument list.

Example in usage

```
function foo(bar, ...baz) {
  console.log(bar);
  console.log(baz); 
}

foo(1, 2, 3, 4);
// 1
// [2, 3, 4]
```

If in some bizarre world, the Rest parameter could be on the first of many parameters, then we'd have something like this

```
// NOT VALID JS
function foo(...bar, baz) {
  console.log(bar);
  console.log(baz); 
}

foo(1, 2, 3, 4);
// [1, 2, 3, 4]
// undefined
```

And what use would that be...?

Comment: Your second example has a reasonable interpretation that `bar` would be `[1, 2, 3]` and `baz` would be `4`. Why couldn't that be supported?

Comment: @torazaburo: that's a fair point.  my suspicion is that as it is defined now, the rest operator always means exactly 1 thing, which is 'take everything else that remains (take the 'rest')'.  i'd suspect the spec (and usage) would get considerably more complicated if the rules could bend in that way...but that's just my guess...

Answer (score 3):

Rest parameter must be last formal parameter
error:

```
function f(a, ...b, c) {
 // ...
}
```

right:

```
function f(a, b, ...c) {
 // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

rest will be behave like default argument in other language(c++)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35109316)